# Dataset of football (soccer) new penalties

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a soccer penalty dataset containing as many following fields as possible:

name of the player who shot the penalty
name of the goalkeeper
penalty outcome (success/fail)
ball position, i.e. where player placed the ball (center, bottom left, )
teams of the player and goalkeeper
time of the penalty during the game
player's position (attackers/midfield/defenders)
datetime of the game
competition name